# Delphi SMTP Email Error "123..."

Tags: delphi, email

I am having a problem with an email function i use to send mails from delphi.
It has always worked. But some how now I cannot use the function.
It gives me an error `System Error. Code:123. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Where can I start looking for this problem?
I am not sure what is even causing this error?

any assistance would be great :).

Code executed:

```
procedure SendEmail(SHost,SUsername,SPassword,SEmail,SPort:String; const Recipients: string; const Subject: string; const Body: string);
var
  SMTP: TIdSMTP;
  Email: TIdMessage;
  SSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  Port:Word;
begin
  SMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  Email := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

  try
    SSLHandler.MaxLineAction := maException;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

    SMTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
    SMTP.Host := SHost;
    //port:=strtoint(sport);
    {If sPort='26' then} port:=26;
    SMTP.Port := Port;
    SMTP.Username := sUsername;
    SMTP.Password := sPassword;
    SMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

    Email.From.Address := sEmail;
    Email.Recipients.EmailAddresses := Recipients;
    Email.Subject := Subject;
    Email.Body.Text := Body;

    SMTP.Connect;
    SMTP.Send(Email);
    SMTP.Disconnect;

  finally
    SMTP.Free;
    Email.Free;
    SSLHandler.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Can you step through and identify the line which causes the error? From what you've said my suspicion would initially fall on the SSLHandler.

Comment: The [`ERROR_INVALID_NAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ERROR_INVALID_NAME) error occurs when you attempt to load a file with an invalid path. This code should not cause this (as long as you didn't change the `GIdOpenSSLPath` variable value).

Comment: @Jaydee the error accours on the smtp.connect; line... So from that I assume, it can be any variable causing the problem.

Comment: @Marcel Yes, the function works well. Can you post the code where you call the function?

Comment: @Marcel: What is the actual value of `SHost`? And why are you connecting to port 26? The standard SMTP ports for `usUseExplicitTLS` are 25 and 587 instead.